# Invalidate () crashing

Tags: android, view, invalidation

I am sending data to a class which i desired to change the layout. I send the data by the followinf way:

while(connected){

```
    //receive data through socket  
    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

    while ( (line = in.readLine()) != null){

        String [] aarray = line.split("[^\\d]+");                

         if (aarray != null){

             for(int i = 0; i < aarray.length; i++){

               number = Integer.parseInt(aarray[i]);

                   }

               }

               Log.d(TAG, "Line " + String.valueOf(line));             

               myCompassView.updateDirection(number);
```

the updateDirection calls the following function:

```
public void updateDirection(float dir){

    direction = dir;
    Log.d(main.TAG, "mudou direction " + String.valueOf(direction));

    invalidate();

}
```

and I wanted this invalidade() to call the onDraw(Canvas canvas) function again, but instead it making the application crash.

I don't understand the problem, I though the invalidate() was pretty straight forward.

If someone could help me, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: are you subclassing a view?

Comment: What is the exception??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `postInvalidate()` instead. Or:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable () {
@Override
public void run() {
    invalidate(view)
}
});
```

Comment: Thank you, postInvalidate() worked great. So I guess it was because I was not posting the request to the UI-thread.